# Adding suite numbers to apartment building?

Tags: arcpy

I wanted to know if there is an easier way to add apartment suite numbers to an apartment property? An example workflow of what I currently do to add a 400 level apartment building is add one point for each building number at the 100 level. I then copy and paste each level from the 100 level series and change the suite field number until I get to the 400 level series. The current process that I go about this seems very archaic and time consuming.

I figure there is a python tool floating around out there that lets me select all of the 100 level series and specify how many levels there are and the tool creates multiple points over the 100 level suite with their appropriate building number.

Comment: I think you will need to write some ArcPy/Python code to do this.